# Error while using "acro" package for abbreviations

Tags: acro

When I tried using `acro` for generating abbreviations and nomenclature, I got the following errors and warnings. I also attached the code below for your reference. I use MiKTeX Console 2.9.7429 and texstudio 2.12.22 currently.

```
LaTeX3 Error: The key 'acro/list/include-classes' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored. ...include-classes=abbrev, name=Abbreviation]
LaTeX3 Error: The key 'acro/list/include-classes' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored. ...include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]
On line 6:(acro) The property `class' is deprecated. Use property `tag'(acro) instead.
On line 11:(acro) The property `class' is deprecated. Use property `tag'(acro) instead.
On line 16:(acro) The property `class' is deprecated. Use property `tag'(acro) instead.
On line 20:(acro) The property `class' is deprecated. Use property `tag'(acro) instead.
On line 24:(acro) The property `class' is deprecated. Use property `tag'(acro) instead.
```

My code is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{alpha}{
    short = \ensuremath{\alpha},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{v}{
    short = \ensuremath{v},
    long  = Velocity,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{V}{
    short = \ensuremath{V},
    long  = Volume,
    class = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Wab}{
    short = \ensuremath{W_{(\alpha,b)}},
    long  = Wavelet Coefficients,
    class = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHDL}{
    short = VHDL,
    long  = VHSIC Hardware Description Language,
    class = abbrev}
\begin{document}
    \ac{alpha}\\ \ac{Wab}
    \printacronyms[include-classes=abbrev, name=Abbreviation]
    \printacronyms[include-classes=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]
\end{document}
```

I think in the last two  `\printacronyms[]` statements,  `include-classes` is giving problem. Because of which, both `alpha` and `Wab` is printed in both abbreviation and nomenclature as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help is well appreciated!

Comment: If you see a warning `The property 'class' is deprecated. Use property 'tag'(acro) instead.` then why don't you do what it says and change class to tag? And regarding the error: check the documentation. It will tell you the correct name of the key to use.

Comment: Since you show a screenshot of the output of a document that results in an error message upon compiling: Please don't look at the output of you recieve an error message. Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did what it said. But instead of just include in used include-tags. Which again gave the same error. Now I fixed it. Thanks for you comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With version 3 of the `acro` package quite some changes to the user interface were made. To make your example code (which was written for version 2) compilable, replace `class` with `tag` in all `\DeclareAcronym` commands (This is exactly what the four warnings tell you to do). To also get rid of the error messages, replace the `include-classes=...` options with `include=...`.

Here is the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{alpha}{
    short = \ensuremath{\alpha},
    long  = Dyadic Dilation,
    tag   = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{v}{
    short = \ensuremath{v},
    long  = Velocity,
    tag   = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{V}{
    short = \ensuremath{V},
    long  = Volume,
    tag   = nomencl}
\DeclareAcronym{Wab}{
    short = \ensuremath{W_{(\alpha,b)}},
    long  = Wavelet Coefficients,
    tag   = abbrev}
\DeclareAcronym{VHDL}{
    short = VHDL,
    long  = VHSIC Hardware Description Language,
    tag   = abbrev}
\begin{document}
    \ac{alpha}\\ \ac{Wab}
    \printacronyms[include=abbrev, name=Abbreviation]
    \printacronyms[include=nomencl,name=Nomenclature]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hey @leandriis, I got the point. Thanks for your support and answer.

Comment: Hey @leandriis, I have a doubt. Your code worked perfect on my personal computer since acro package in my computer is version 3. But when I tried your code in overleaf, I get ```LaTeX3 Error: The key 'acro/list/include-classes' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored. ...include=abbrev, name=Abbreviation]``` and ```LaTeX3 Error: The key 'acro/list/tag' is unknown and is being(LaTeX3) ignored```. But when put version 2 code, that is my code in the question, it works perfect in overleaf. Will overleaf use the latest version of a package or it is mandatory to update the package in ove

Comment: In overleaf you can select between differen Tex Live versions. The most recent version they currently offer is TeXLive 2019. Since version 3 of the `acro` package was released in april 2020 it is not part of Tex Live 2019.

Comment: Is there any other way that you know to use version 3 acro in overleaf?