# Acro package update errors

Tags: acro, texlive-2021

I have been using texlive 2019 with acro Version 2.9, when I upgrade the latex distribution to 2021 with acro V3.5, I got too many errors, it is a 300 pages docment, how to solve the errors without solving them one by one.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
    sort = true ,
    page-style = comma ,
    extra-style = paren ,
    hyperref =true 
}
\DeclareAcronym{CDMA}{
    short            = CDMA ,
    long             = Code Division Multiple Access ,
    long-plural      = es,
    class= foo
}
\DeclareAcronym{GSM}{
    short            = GSM ,
    long             = Global System for Mobile communication,
    class= foo
}
\DeclareAcronym{NA}{
    short            = {\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm{A}}}} ,
    long             = Number of Avogadro ,
    extra            = see \S\ref{Chem} ,
    pdfstring        = NA,
    class= foo
}
\DeclareAcronym{NAD+}{
    short            = {NAD\textsuperscript{+}} ,
    short-plural     = ,
    long             = Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide ,
    pdfstring        = NAD+ ,
    class= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{NUA}{
    short            = NUA ,
    long             = Not Used Acronym,
    class= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{TDMA}{
    short            = TDMA ,
    long             = Time Division Multiple Access ,
    long-plural      = es,
    class= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{UA}{
    short            = UA ,
    long             = Used Acronym,
    class= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{lox}{
    short            = {\emph{LOX}} ,
    long             = Liquid Oxygen ,
    pdfstring        = LOX,
    class= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{lh2}{
    short            = {\emph{LH\textsubscript{2}}} ,
    long             = Liquid Hydrogen ,
    pdfstring        = LH2,
    class= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{IC}{
    short            = IC ,
    long             = Integrated Circuit,
    class= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{BUT}{
    short            = BUT ,
    long             = Block Under Test ,
    long-plural-form = Blocks Under Test ,
    class= baz
}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.3]{Arial}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Arial}
\begin{document}
\printacronyms[name=Foo,include=foo]
\printacronyms[name=Baz,include=baz]
\newpage
\acs{GSM}
\ac{TDMA}
\acs{GSM}
\ac{CDMA}    
\ac{TDMA}
\ac{GSM} 
\acs{GSM}\ac{GSM}\ac{TDMA}.
\ac{CDMA}\acs{GSM}
 \acs{GSM} \ac{TDMA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/546356/2388

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: your example compiles without errors for me after the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After correcting the changed option names from version 2.X to 3.X of package `acro` I can compile without errors the following code (See changings marked with `<======`):

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{acro}
\acsetup{
    list/sort = true , % <==============================================
%   page-style = comma , % <========================== removed from acro
%   extra-style = paren , % <========================= removed from acro
    make-links = true  % <==============================================
}
\DeclareAcronym{CDMA}{
    short            = CDMA ,
    long             = Code Division Multiple Access ,
    long-plural      = es,
    tag= foo % <========================================================
}
\DeclareAcronym{GSM}{
    short            = GSM ,
    long             = Global System for Mobile communication,
    tag= foo % <========================================================
}
\DeclareAcronym{NA}{
    short            = {\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm{A}}}} ,
    long             = Number of Avogadro ,
    extra            = see \S\ref{Chem} ,
    pdfstring        = NA,
    tag= foo
}
\DeclareAcronym{NAD+}{
    short            = {NAD\textsuperscript{+}} ,
    short-plural     = ,
    long             = Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide ,
    pdfstring        = NAD+ ,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{NUA}{
    short            = NUA ,
    long             = Not Used Acronym,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{TDMA}{
    short            = TDMA ,
    long             = Time Division Multiple Access ,
    long-plural      = es,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{UA}{
    short            = UA ,
    long             = Used Acronym,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{lox}{
    short            = {\emph{LOX}} ,
    long             = Liquid Oxygen ,
    pdfstring        = LOX,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{lh2}{
    short            = {\emph{LH\textsubscript{2}}} ,
    long             = Liquid Hydrogen ,
    pdfstring        = LH2,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{IC}{
    short            = IC ,
    long             = Integrated Circuit,
    tag= baz
}
\DeclareAcronym{BUT}{
    short            = BUT ,
    long             = Block Under Test ,
    long-plural-form = Blocks Under Test ,
    tag= baz
}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.3]{Amiri}
\setlatintextfont[Scale=1.3]{Arial}
\defpersianfont\Sayeh[Scale=1.5]{Arial}


\begin{document}
\printacronyms[name=Foo,include=foo]
\printacronyms[name=Baz,include=baz]
\newpage
\acs{GSM}
\ac{TDMA}
\acs{GSM}
\ac{CDMA}    
\ac{TDMA}
\ac{GSM} 
\acs{GSM}\ac{GSM}\ac{TDMA}.
\ac{CDMA}\acs{GSM}
 \acs{GSM} \ac{TDMA}
\end{document}
```